# How to block dfsvc.exe from running in WebBrowser or work around the error C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am loading a site through a proxy using the WinFoms WebBrowser,
after loading a couple of requests, dfsvc.exe is loading and an error occurs
How to work around or prevent dfsvc.exe from starting

I need to get the page code after executing the js scripts on the stage page and close the WebBrowser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAF1t.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNubK.png)

Comment: Launching a click-once installer from a custom browser control seems complicated to start with, is this an intentional design choice? Are you aware of what is being installed?

Comment: Hi, I just need to get data from the page after executing js scripts and close the browser